# Fallback levels of choosing resource file in resource manager chooses default instead parent

Tags: c#, resourcemanager, resource-files

I have resource files for languages named as 
*Resource.en-US.resx, Resource.en-GB.resx, Resource.en.resx, Resource.es-ES.resx, Resource.es-MX.resx, Resource.es.resx, Resource.resx ->English*

When I give the `CultureInfo` for language code `es-ES` I get the correct translation. But when I send `es-US` I get English. But I want the resource file *Resource.es.resx* to be chosen if the current culture resource file is not present.

```
 CultureInfo cul = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-US");
    //Parent shows es
    var parent = cul.Parent;
    ResourceManager   res_man = new ResourceManager("Resources.Resource",typeof(Resources.Resource).Assembly);
    var str = res_man.GetString("Hello", cul);
```

Output -> Hello

Expected -> Hola

Comment: I tested your code and it works perfectly already, I get "Hola" even for `es-CH`

Comment: The same code seems to work in a new console application with referencing the same project Resources. But in the application where its actually being used is not working.  Am i missing any config level changes thats being overridden or to be checked

Comment: Maybe. Can you post the config file for your application? If you can't post it fully, at least the  `<satelliteassemblies>` branch?